VBA Date Modified by cell in multiple columns
Very new to vba, but I am trying to get where if any changes are made to cells in column A or column D, for the NOW date to display in column F. I found something on this that is very similar but looks through just on column for range and the output changes with "offset" causing the NOW date not to stay in column F.
Video Reference: Excel Automatically Date and Time Stamp When Data is Entered but Don't Change When Data is Modified (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23-RoK1p7tg)
So I would like to do something very similar but for the code to look through two columns instead of one, as shown in the video. In the video it only checks for changes in range A2:A10. I would like to check in range for example A2:A10 and in range D2:D10.
However, I would like the NOW date to still be placed in a single column, Column F, so that a change in either range/column, updates this date.
So basically, a change in a column A or column D would display NOW in column F.
Is this possible and if so how will this code be modified?
I've tried this:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MyDataRng As Range
Set MyDataRng = Range("A2:D10")
If Intersect (Target, MyDataRng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
Target.Offset(0, 5) = Now
End Sub

It looks through all the columns which is whatever, but most importantly it doesn't give the NOW date in the same column and offsets it obviously.

Try something like this code:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MyDataRng As Range
    Set MyDataRng = Range("A2:A10,D2:D10")
    If Intersect(Target, MyDataRng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
'    On Error Resume Next
    Cells(Target.Row, "F").Value = Now
End Sub


The basic code to solve your problem is:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim MyDataRng As Range
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    
    Set wks = Me
    Set MyDataRng = wks.Range("A2:D10")
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' Start error-handling routine
    
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, MyDataRng) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            wks.Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = Now
            GoTo ProcExit
        End If
    End If

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub

Please also have a look at Excel VBA Table to Uppercase When Leaving Cell for more in-depth discussion on the subject.

Doesn't this consider cells in the range B2:C10, whereas OP asked for A2:A10 and D2:D10?

@BigBen It's not the most disputable item here.

MyDataRng and wks are extra variables (side note). Since you've created the so detailed handler, you need to process the case Target.CountLarge > 1 (or IsArray(Target)).

@BigBen 5 is not F, additionally.

Let me to allow myself to present modified @Michal's code which is able to process the multiple cells change event:
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim isr As Range, cc
  On Error GoTo ClearError
  Set isr = Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A10, D2:D10"))
  If isr Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  For Each cc In isr
    Cells(cc.Row, 6).Value = Now
  Next
  Application.EnableEvents = True
ProcExit:
  Exit Sub
ClearError:
  MsgBox "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
      & Err.Description, vbCritical
  Resume ProcExit
End Sub


How is it going?
